# How to save attachments in a physical location of an object in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Hi I want to get all attachments from SAS content server of solution EGRC 6.1 policy object and want to save it in a physical location on my server.

This is what I'm doing now.

```
proc sql noprint;
select BUSINESS_OBJECT_RK 
into: rk saperated by '-'
from sasoprsk.attachment_l
where BUSINESS_OBJECT_NM eq "POLICY_INST"
and   ATTACHMENT_TYPE_CD ne "LNK";

select FILE_NM 
into: file saperated by '-'
from sasoprsk.attachment_l
where BUSINESS_OBJECT_NM eq "POLICY_INST"
and   ATTACHMENT_TYPE_CD ne "LNK";

quit;


%macro attachment;

proc sql noprint;
select count(*) 
into: count
from sasoprsk.attachment_l
where BUSINESS_OBJECT_NM eq "POLICY_INST"
and   ATTACHMENT_TYPE_CD ne "LNK";
quit;

%do i = 1 %to &count;

filename out temp;

    %let rk_l=%scan(%bquote(&rk), %bquote(&i) ,%str(-));
    %let file_l=%scan(%bquote(&file), %bquote(&i) ,%str(-));

%put "file &file_l";
%put "http://sasbap.demo.sas.com/SASContentServer/repository/default/sasdav/Products/SASEnterpriseGRC/EnterpriseGRCMidTier6.1/Content/policy/&rk_l/&file_l"; 

proc http 
method="get"
url="http://sasbap.demo.sas.com/SASContentServer/repository/default/sasdav/Products/SASEnterpriseGRC/EnterpriseGRCMidTier6.1/Content/policy/&rk_l/&file_l"
webUserName="sas"
webPassword="Orion123"
out=out;
run;

%end;
%mend;  

%attachment;
```

I'm saving my attachment files in temp file but I want to save in a physical location as "C drive" inside a folder named as their rk of my objrct with proper extension as file.doc, file.xls or file.jpg etc.

```
example 
obj_nm        rk      file_nm
POLICY_INST   12      file.xls
POLICY_INST   13      file.doc
POLICY_INST   14      file.gif
```

I want to put those files as

```
C:/12/file.xls 
C:/13/file.doc
C:/14/file.gif
```

Kindly tell me how can I save my files from SAS content server to a physical location of my server with proper extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following before your `proc http` call:

```
%mf_mkdir(C:/&rk_l)
filename out "C:/&rk_l/&file_l";
```

The source code for `mf_mkdir` is available in the open source MacroCore [library](https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/base/mf_mkdir.sas), and is reproduced below:

```
/**
  @file
  @brief Creates a directory, including any intermediate directories
  @details Works on windows and unix environments via dcreate function.
Usage:

    %mf_mkdir(/some/path/name)


  @param dir relative or absolute pathname.  Unquoted.
  @version 9.2
  @copyright GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE v3
**/

%macro mf_mkdir(dir
)/*/STORE SOURCE*/;

  %local lastchar child parent;

  %let lastchar = %substr(&dir, %length(&dir));
  %if (%bquote(&lastchar) eq %str(:)) %then %do;
    /* Cannot create drive mappings */
    %return;
  %end;

  %if (%bquote(&lastchar)=%str(/)) or (%bquote(&lastchar)=%str(\)) %then %do;
    /* last char is a slash */
    %if (%length(&dir) eq 1) %then %do;
      /* one single slash - root location is assumed to exist */
      %return;
    %end;
    %else %do;
      /* strip last slash */
      %let dir = %substr(&dir, 1, %length(&dir)-1);
    %end;
  %end;

  %if (%sysfunc(fileexist(%bquote(&dir))) = 0) %then %do;
    /* directory does not exist so prepare to create */
    /* first get the childmost directory */
    %let child = %scan(&dir, -1, %str(/\:));

    /*
      If child name = path name then there are no parents to create. Else
      they must be recursively scanned.
    */

    %if (%length(&dir) gt %length(&child)) %then %do;
       %let parent = %substr(&dir, 1, %length(&dir)-%length(&child));
       %mf_mkdir(&parent);
    %end;

    /*
      Now create the directory.  Complain loudly of any errors.
    */

    %let dname = %sysfunc(dcreate(&child, &parent));
    %if (%bquote(&dname) eq ) %then %do;
       %put ERROR: could not create &parent\&child;
       %abort cancel;
    %end;
    %else %do;
       %put Directory created:  &dir;
    %end;
  %end;
  /* exit quietly if directory did exist.*/
%mend;
```